# How to get sibling input field value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have form that has two input fields in same row. Here is example:

```js
$(".qtr-date").on("change", function() {
  let $curr_field = $(this);
  let $next_field = $curr_field.parent().parent().next().find('input.qtr-date');
  let start_dt = new Date($curr_field.val());
  let end_dt = new Date($next_field.val());

  console.log(start_dt);
  console.log(end_dt);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-group row ml-0">
  <label for="quarter-1" class="col-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold">1st Quarter</label>
  <div class="col-5">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span></span>
      <input class="form-control qtr-date" type="text" name="q1_start" id="q1_start" value="01/31/2020" data-initial="01/31/2020" data-label="1st Quarter Start" required="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-5">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span></span>
      <input class="form-control qtr-date" type="text" name="q1_end" id="q1_end" value="12/31/2020" data-initial="12/31/2020" data-label="1st Quarter End" required="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the example above if I click on 1st Quarter Start Date console will output both values Start / End date. The I clicked on the end date and changed the value. The console printed start date value but end date value was null. I see the issue since my code is only working for scenario when user clicks on Start Date, but I would like this to work the other way around as well. if user clicks on ether Start or End date both values show print in the console. If anyone knows easy way to fix that please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the issue use `closest()` to retrieve a common parent of the target inputs, `.form-group` in the following example, then use `find()` to retrieve the values from them both.

```js
$(".qtr-date").on("change", function() {
  let $container = $(this).closest('.form-group');
  let start_dt = new Date($container.find('.qtr-date:first').val());
  let end_dt = new Date($container.find('.qtr-date:last').val());

  console.log(start_dt);
  console.log(end_dt);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-group row ml-0">
  <label for="quarter-1" class="col-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold">1st Quarter</label>
  <div class="col-5">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span></span>
      <input class="form-control qtr-date" type="text" name="q1_start" id="q1_start" value="01/31/2020" data-initial="01/31/2020" data-label="1st Quarter Start" required="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-5">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span></span>
      <input class="form-control qtr-date" type="text" name="q1_end" id="q1_end" value="12/31/2020" data-initial="12/31/2020" data-label="1st Quarter End" required="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```